# Output of allelic association doesn't write the rsID

Tags: snp, phylogenetics, ngs, plink

I'm using plink (1.9b5) to do allelic association. My problem is that my output does not write the `rsID` (SNP), it just writes a dot.

Output:

```
CHR SNP  BP   A1  F_A      F_U      A2  P       OR           
1   .    1014 A   0.18     0.07     C   0.22    3.03
```

My script:

```
plink --bed file.bed --bim file.bim --fam file.fam --make-bed --out output
```

Can someone please help me see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please show the first few lines of the `.bim` file? That will help to establish whether or not there is rs information in there for Plink to use.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from @user438383, converted from comment:*

It seems likely your input .bim file probably doesn't have RSIDs either - is that the case?